# Calculating avg score and returning a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to complete an exercise where I need to calculate an average score and return a string "Your average score is XX"

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    return (str("your score is"), round((a+b+c)/3,1))

report_exam_avg(2,5,9)
```

When I run this, nothing is returned and I am not sure how to return a string without using a print statement. Thank you.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must print the returned value, or print it in the function, it would be easier to print it in the function.

Better Solution:

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    print("Your score is", round((a+b+c)/3,1))

report_exam_avg(2,5,9)
```

or this also works:

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
  return("Your score is " + str(round((a+b+c)/3,1)))

print(report_exam_avg(2,5,9))
```

Comment: Printing a value in a function instead of returning it is never a better solution. Such value cannot be further reused.

Comment: @DYZ "Never" is a strong word.

Answer (score 0):

`return "your score is " + str(round(a + b + c) / 3, 1))`

Best way is to use one of the format options, either `%` or `"string".format()`. But this way is the simplest and most intuitive way. You can add strings, so convert the number to a string and add it to "your score is ".

Comment: Wouldn't the best way be to print it in the function as I detailed in my answer?

Comment: @AaronD.Rodriguez I agree with DYZ. Your solution works fine, but it's better to keep calculation logic and printing separate from one another.

Comment: @JaneBugai Make sure you mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a string and print it when in need. You should either use string formatting to place numbers within a string:

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    return "your score is %.1f" % (round((a+b+c)/3,1))

print(report_exam_avg(2,5,9)) # your score is 5
```

Or, use string addition, but after converting the numbers to string:

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    return "your score is " + str(round((a+b+c)/3,1))

print(report_exam_avg(2,5,9)) # your score is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You must `print` the return value. Also, you might want to use string formatting for the output (it can also do rounding for you).

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    return "your score is {:.0f}".format((a+b+c) / 3)

print(report_exam_avg(2,5,9))
```

---

```
your score is 5
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6+ you can `return f"your score is {((a+b+c) / 3):.0f}"` using f-strings

Comment: @Jaba You're totally right, but just for compatibility reasons, I used the normal `format` syntax.

Comment: No worries, it's a shame they're not backwards compatible they're so nice to work with than others.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to separate the computation and presentation. Let your function calculate and return the average. Let the caller print it.

```
def report_exam_avg(a, b, c):
    return (a + b + c) / 3

score = report_exam_avg(2, 5, 9)
print("Your average score is {:.0f}".format(score))
```

Note that `format` is also doing the rounding, so the call to `round()` is not necessary.